# How to use @{{ }} without escaping the braces in blade?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have my routes for user profiles like so `example.com/@username`. So now I want to say something like this:

```html
<a href="/@{{ $user->name }}">Go to {{ $user->name }} profile</a>
```

But this actually escapes the `{{ $user->name }}` in `href` attribute (as said [in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#blade-and-javascript-frameworks)), so this will literally redirect me to `example.com/{{ $user->name }}`.

Of course, I can use the pure php way like `@<?= $user->name; ?>` or any other way. But I want to use laravel's curly braces `{{  }}`.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<a href="{{ url('/@'.$user->name) }}">Go to {{ $user->name }} profile</a>
```

Comment: You don't need that `/` fyi `url('@'.$user->name)` will do the same job there :-)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to work this problem around is to use the above answer. It will make use of blade's `{{ }}`.

However, I recommend another (semi) approach. You can create a method for the `User` model (in my case) like so:

```php
class User {
   public function handle()
    {
        return '@' . $this->username;
    }
}
```

Then you can use:

```html
<a href="/{{ $user->handle }}">Go to {{ $user->name }} profile</a>
```

As I said, this is not a general solution. But it works for my case. If you want more general solution, refer to the above answer.